# AngularJS filtering on clicked span element removes data from table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the following [codepen](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/oNNPNMK?editors=1010) I am trying to use a filter in the ng-repeat attribute to filter based on which span element is being clicked or on text being entered in the search text box. I am using a table to show trouble ticket data with the columns ID, Ticket Description, Ticket Status and Edit.

The problem is it works when you click on the Open or Closed span but the All span does the opposite of what its intent is. The All span should show all the rows. Attempting to filter in the search box also removes all the data.

How can I show all data when the All span is clicked and enable searching in the text box. The reason I used "filter:searchText:true:Status" is because there are sometimes words in another column (Ticket Description column) that have words like Open and Closed. I've been reading filter [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) but still not sure how to implement this for my purpose. Thank you.

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 my-auto">
          <span ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-click="update(tab.value)">{{tab.label}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 my-auto">
          <label class="my-auto float-right">Search:
            <input ng-model="searchText">
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row table-responsive">
        <table id="searchTextResults" class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th ng-click="sortBy('ID')">ID</th>
                <th ng-click="sortBy('Description')">Ticket Description</th>
                <th ng-click="sortBy('Status')">Ticket Status</th>
              <th>Edit</th>
            </tr>
          <tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="ticket in tickets | filter:searchText | filter:searchText:true:Status | orderBy:sortField:reverseOrder">
              <td><a href="#">{{ticket.ID}}</a></td>
              <td><a href="#">{{ticket.Description}}</a></td>
              <td><a href="#">{{ticket.Status}}</a></td>
<td><button ng-click="openModal()" class="myBtn">Edit</button></td>
            </tr>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Portion of AngularJS code

```
 $scope.tabs = [ 
   { value: '', label: 'All' }, 
   { value: 'Open', label: 'Open'},
   { value: 'Closed', label: 'Closed'}
 ]; 
    
 $scope.update = function(filterText) {
      $scope.searchText = filterText;
 }
```

Comment: If you remove ```filter:searchText:true:Status``` then it works as intended, the ```filter:searchText``` itself enough to filter the data in the entire table.. If you even type Open or Closed then the respective data will be displayed with ```filter:searchText``` itself..

Comment: But then when you click Closed it will also show the row that has the word Closed its description but whose status is Open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason that this is not working for the search bar is because the **:true:** segment makes it do a strictly equalTo search. In order to fix the issue. Create two different filter variables. One for a strict search applied directly to status. and one for the search field. You will need to rebind the ng-model to var2.

```
ng-model="var2"
```

`filter:var2`

`filter:searchText:true:Status`

resulting in the following:

```
ticket in tickets | filter:var2 | filter:searchText:true:Status | orderBy:sortField:reverseOrder
```

Then on the js side I am going to be a little lazy and just add the code.

```
$scope.var2="";
$scope.tabs = [ 
   { value: undefined, label: 'All' }, 
   { value: 'Open', label: 'Open'},
   { value: 'Closed', label: 'Closed'}
 ];
```

Comment: Haha sorry, it is the end of the day, but these changes will fix your code. I tested in codePen. Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: Thank you Zera. I have one question. When you say rebind the ng-model to var2 does that mean change the current ng-model="searchText to ng-model="var2"?